# Is it better to run a synchronous http request in a separate thread or just run an async http request?

Tags: c#, .net

Technically its the same thing. Running a sync routine in a separate thread is effectively running it asynchronously. But is there really any difference and which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the async version of the method. They've already been optimized to use the least amount of resources and will effectively create a new thread *if needed*. Generally most async methods end up executing in the thread pool which is usually a good thing.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since you were the first. Others have said similar things, although some more witty (Marino).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely async.

> Technically its the same thing.

No, it is not. because synchronous method blocks the thread, thus rendering it unusable for any different work. Asynchronous releases the thread, thus it can do different work. And when async finishes, it uses new thread.

While this is not much problem form simple synchronous/asynchronous calls. It can be extremly beneficial to use async, when you run dozens or maybe thousands of calls. And your can spawn many more calls parallel AT THE SAME TIME using async, because this is handled by OS and framework itself. You would need to write your own logic if you wanted to run your calls in parallel.

Comment: Euphoric, the question was about a sync request in a separate thread (technically async). Not just a general sync vs. async question. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Andrew : >(technically async) Thats what I'm telling is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Async methods tells the framework to use [IO Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for notification on the socket, and then when the IO finishes, it runs the completion routines on the thread pool.

While multi-threading is used, it's used very efficiently, without the need to create additional threads just for this purpose, and without tying up a thread just waiting for the IO to finish.

In contrast, the classic thread-per-connection mechanism creates a new new thread for the specific purpose of waiting of waiting for IO to finish, which is a real waste of resources.

While the performance difference between the two methods isn't going to be visible in the simple case, the real difference shows up when you try to scale up. It's very difficult to get decent performance with a thread-per-connection model above a few thousand (or even a few hundred) simultaneous connections because of the increased overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The async request is optimized for that type of behavior and requires less mental gymnastics.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a separate thread that runs a request synchroneusly instead of calling the Async version you have **successfully run an async request**.

Do this in loops and you have **successfully killed the server** that is running the code.

Then you will start to create you own thread pool, synching mechanisms etc, etc to avoid this situation.

Than you can say you have reinvented the wheel, that microsoft created before you :)